# Formatting returned value to 2 decimal places in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

I have the query below that retrieves data from my database on which it sums up all values and divide it to 60 to convert it to hours:

```
SELECT date(att.`date`) as dtDate, 
(select sum(early_leave) from `attendance` where `attendance`.early_leave
> 0 and date(`attendance`.`date`) = date(att.date)) / 60 as EL

FROM `attendance` as att 

where date(att.`date`) BETWEEN '2018-08-9' and '2018-08-23'
group by date(att.`date`)
order by date(att.`date`)
```

It's output is like this:

[image: output 1]

And now, I want it to format with 2 decimal places, so I do:

```
SELECT date(att.`date`) as dtDate, 
(select format(sum(early_leave),2) from `attendance` where `attendance`.early_leave
> 0 and date(`attendance`.`date`) = date(att.date)) / 60 as EL

FROM `attendance` as att 

where date(att.`date`) BETWEEN '2018-08-9' and '2018-08-23'
group by date(att.`date`)
order by date(att.`date`)
```

But why some of the outputs are like this:

[image: output 2]

I'm expecting the second value on `2018-08-10` to be `28` and so on. Does somebody knows why is it happening like this? Or am I formatting it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the `format` as the last thing as the divide by 60 will cause extra decimal places in the result:

```
format((select sum(early_leave) from `attendance` where `attendance`.early_leave
> 0 and date(`attendance`.`date`) = date(att.date)) / 60, 2) as EL
```

If you don't want to display unneeded decimal places, just add 0!

```
format((select sum(early_leave) from `attendance` where `attendance`.early_leave
> 0 and date(`attendance`.`date`) = date(att.date)) / 60, 2)+0 as EL
```

For example:

```
select format(2.00,2)+0, format(1.5,2)+0, format(1.55,2)+0
```

Output:

```
2, 1.5, 1.55
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I also have discovered it this way (the first one), and my problem now is if it's a whole number, like `17.00` return shoud be 17 and if has `.50` return should be .5. If you can extend more help on this please. Thanks.'

Comment: @ramj see my edit, it will allow you to get rid of unwanted decimal places

Answer (score 1):

> which it sums up all values and divide it to 60 to convert it to hours

Are you sure you want to divide something by 60 to convert it to hours? That assumes `early_leave` is stored in minutes. Is this the case?

About the formatting. You need to format the second column as a whole:

```
(select format(sum(early_leave),2) from `attendance` where `attendance`.early_leave
> 0 and date(`attendance`.`date`) = date(att.date)) / 60
```

Change it to

```
CAST((select format(sum(early_leave),2) from `attendance` where `attendance`.early_leave
> 0 and date(`attendance`.`date`) = date(att.date)) / 60 AS DECIMAL(12,2))
```

This, however, will not solve your problem. If some results are correct and some are not, the issue is most likely the calculation or the source data.

On a side note, the original query is a bit messy. Instead of using a subquery, a better solution is to join that table. Something like this (not tested, but it demonstrates my point).

```
SELECT
  DATE(`att`.`date`) AS `dtDate`, 
  CAST(SUM(`att2`.`early_leave`) / 60 AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS `EL`
FROM `attendance` AS `att`
INNER JOIN `attendance` AS `att2`
  ON `att2`.`early_leave` > 0 AND DATE(`att2`.`date`) = DATE(`att`.`date`)
WHERE DATE(`att`.`date`) BETWEEN '2018-08-9' and '2018-08-23'
GROUP BY DATE(`att`.`date`)
ORDER BY DATE(`att`.`date`)
```